# Splitting resources with android libraries

Tags: android, android-library, android-resources, r.java-file

I have an android project where a couple of strings, images and the database need to be altered to suit each client (These would be separate apps rather than, for example, a customer entering their name). 
As far as I can tell, the best way for me to do this is with a library handling all of the GUIs and logic but then changing the necessary things in the project using it. Unfortunately the library seems to look for layouts in the parent project's `res/layout` folder but still requires those same files in its own `res/layout` folder in order to generate `R.java`. This basically means I am having to deal with duplicate copies of resources.

My question is basically this: Is it possible for my project to use the resources from the library (as opposed to the parent project) except for a few resources held within the parent project (Which can be referenced in code within the library)?

Otherwise, is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unfortunately the library seems to look for layouts in the parent project's res/layout folder but still requires those same files in its own res/layout folder in order to generate R.java. This basically means I am having to deal with duplicate copies of resources.

True, though the copy in the library would simply be your defaults. You would only override them in the hosting project if you needed to replace them. Hence, the only places where there will be "duplicates" is where the files are actually different.

> Is it possible for my project to use the resources from the library (as opposed to the parent project) except for a few resources held within the parent project (Which can be referenced in code within the library)?

Only if you modify your library's API to accept resource IDs as parameters, rather than assuming certain resources by `R` name. For example, most of the Android SDK uses resource IDs as parameters on methods (e.g., `setContentView()`) rather than assuming the name of a resource to use (e.g., `R.layout.main`).

> Otherwise, is there a better way to handle this?

Your original approach seemed fine to me.